# How can I force a Maven clean?

Tags: maven, windows-xp

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 on WinXP and running my Maven build commands through Cygwin.  Occassionally, I'll be able to run a maven clean ...

```
 mvn clean install
```

And I'll get errors like ...

```
[INFO] Deleting C:\Documents and Settings\E18538\workspace\iteration1\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.891s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 23 11:07:58 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project myco-productplus-web: Failed to clean project:Failed to delete C:\Documents and Settings\E18538\workspace\iteration1\target -> [Help 1]
```

Other than Cygwin, I'll close all other applications, but there is still a process holding something in "target".  How do I figure out what that process is and then kill it?  Note that when I restart my system, I can again run "mvn clean" commands.

**Edit**: The process that is holding onto the directory in question is "TGitCache.exe", spawned by TortoiseGit, installed on my system.  I have marked the "target" directory as one to ignore, so I'm wondering if there's a way to cause this process to ignore target.

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Windows problem.... Check that you don't have a file explorer (or editor) open under the "target" directory path.

Comment: I have had a similar problem and found it was my IDE (Eclipse) building my project at the same time I am trying to do a maven build. Don't know if this applies to you but thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 6):

Run `mvn -X clean` to see the actual error stacktrace to figure out what's wrong. As to check what is locking the directory see [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/).

Comment: `-X` won't help him, but +1 for seeing what locks the directory.

Comment: Hi, Unlocker helped me figure out what process is holding onto the "target" directory.  Although I could kill the process each time, I'd like to find a longer term solution.  I'm going to update my question with my findings, but if I need to open a new question, I'll let the SO gods determine that.

Answer (score 2):

Use mvn clean -Dmaven.clean.failOnError=false
to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring(Eclipse) to do a maven clean and already had a command line and cygwin open with target as the current directory. I closed cygwin and other console, did a maven clean on the pom.xml in Spring and it worked!

This link helped me out: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/faq.html